# Loading multiple YAML files (using @ConfigurationProperties?)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, snakeyaml

Using Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE

I have a couple of yaml files that describe several instances of a program. I now want to parse all those files into a `List<Program>` (Map, whatever), so I can later on search for the most appropriate instance for a given criteria in all the programs.

I like the approach with `@ConfigurationProperties` a lot, and it works good enough for a single yaml-file, but I haven't found a way yet to read all files in a directory using that method.

Current approach working for a single file:

```
programs/program1.yml

name: Program 1
minDays: 4
maxDays: 6
```

can be read by

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:programs/program1.yml", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class ProgramProperties {

private Program test; //Program is a POJO with all the fields in the yml.
//getters+setters
```

I tried changing the locations to an Array listing all of my files `locations = {"classpath:programs/program1.yml", "classpath:programs/program2.yml"}` as well as using `locations = "classpath:programs/*.yml"`, but that still only loads the first file (array-approach) or nothing at all (wildcard-approach).

So, my question is, what is the best way in Spring Boot to load a bunch of yaml files in a classpath-directory and parse them into a (List of) POJO, so they can be autowired in a Controller? Do I need to use Snakeyaml directly, or is there an integrated mechanism that I just haven't found yet?

EDIT:
A working approach is doing it manually:

```
    private static final Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(Program.class));
private static final ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();

try {
        for (Resource resource : resolver.getResources("/programs/*.yml")) {

            Object data = yaml.load(resource.getInputStream());

            programList.add((Program) data);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        logger.error("failed to load resource", ioe);
    }
```

Comment: A wildcard won't work AFAIK, but using an array should work, however you seem to have forgot the `classpath:` prefix in that.

Comment: thanks for the input, I edited my text above - as I naturally had it in my code when trying around.
However, if this approach SHOULD work, how would I have to write my class (or change the yaml-structure?) that the Program isn't just filled with the data from the first yaml-file, but becomes a list of all the different Programs?

Answer (score 3):

In Spring, it is possible to load multiple configuration properties files using `PropertySource` annotation, but not YAML files. See section 26.6.4 in link below:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

However, from your problem, it seems that you can configure all your programs in single YAML and then get all list of programs in a single list.

Sample YAML (all.yaml)

```
programs:
  - name: A
    min: 1
    max: 2
  - name: B
    min: 3
    max: 4
```

Config.java

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(locations={"classpath:all.yaml"})
public class Config{

    private List<Program> programs;

    public void setPrograms(List<Program> programs) {
        this.programs = programs;
    }

    public List<Program> getPrograms() {
        return programs;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks mohit, this definitely works and was my first approach as well, but I wanted to go the separate file route as a single program can get quite big and the resulting "all.yaml" would be a horror to maintain...

Comment: Well, in such case, you can use @ConfigurationProperties annotation on a method and then load the configuration by writing your own code. This approach is more of what you included in question with additional advantage of auto-wiring the List<Programs>.

Comment: Just and FYI: the `locations` argument in `@ConfigurationProperties` was depreciated in 1.4 "in favor of configuring the environment directly with additional locations".

Answer (score 3):

What I am currently doing, as far as I understood your question, is nearly the same.
I am having an `application.yml` and also profile-specific yml files, e.g. `application-{profile}.yml` in my `src/main/resources`.
In the `application.yml` I have defined the default profile key-values, which are partially overridden by the profile-specific yml files.

If you want to have a type-safe and well defined access of your YML key/values, then you can use the following approach:

```
 @ConfigurationProperties
 public class AppSettings {
     String name; // has to be the same as the key in your yml file

     // setters/getters

 }
```

In your Spring-Boot config, you have to add the following annotations onto your config class:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties( value = { AppSettings.class, SomeOtherSettings.class } )
public class SpringContextConfig {

     @Autowired
     private AppSettings appSettings;

     public void test() {
          System.out.println(appSettings.getName());
     }
}
```

The `@Autowiring` is also accessible from other Beans. 
The other way around (without an extra separated and type-safe class, is to access the YML-values via `@Value("${name}")`.

To bring it together in a short manner:
Yes, it is possible to use several YAML files for your application via Spring-profiles. You define your current active spring profile via command args, programmatically or via your system env (SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=name1,name2).
Therefore you can have several `application.yml` files for each profile (see above).

Comment: I do not think this was a question regarding how to name different profile application.yml files.