# Spring Boot 2.x binding YAML list into class problems

Tags: spring, spring-boot

So I have been trying to a `list` property from my `YAML` to a class that I made and somehow the list binding can only recognize comma-separated values from the YAML.

Given this class

```
@Getter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:test.yml")
public class SomeProperty {
    final List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And this yaml file

```
someList:
  - a
  - b
```

If I `autowire` the `SomeProperty` somewhere and print the `someList`, it will return an empty list, but if I change the yaml file to this

```
someList: a,b
```

Then the binding works and returns an array list containing the values. What is the problem with the binding?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind yaml list to a java list in springboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734469/how-to-bind-yaml-list-to-a-java-list-in-springboot)

Comment: @pringi No, that approach assumes that the yaml file I want to bind is the default application.yml. What I want to achieve is bind another external yaml file. Although I have discovered the problem, it is with PropertySource as it only recognizes property formats of key-value pairs

Comment: This has an example like you are trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063678/loading-multiple-yaml-files-using-configurationproperties

Comment: Yea, unfortunately, that approach has already been deprecated. Locations parameter for the ConfigurationProperties no longer exists

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that PropertySource can only recognize *.properties files that is why it cannot recognize yaml lists.